# Wget a page that requires logging in

Tags: windows, wget, cookies

I’m trying to figure out a way to use [Wget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) or a similar tool so that I can schedule a web page to be downloaded regularly as a sort of updating log. The problem is that the page requires that I be logged in. Otherwise I get a different page, generic.

Further, the page does not take login information as [GET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) parameters in the URL; it uses [POST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) to log in on the login page and cookies to save the login information that’s read by the regular page.

I’m currently using `GNU Wget 1.10.2` for Windows. I’ve tried using Wget’s cookie functionality, but I have had mixed results, usually skewing towards it not working.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: I've heard that curl and PHP can do it but am not sure how

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/257831/how-to-download-a-file-behind-authentication-via-wget-or-curl.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution, after being logged in in the browser, and if you don't want to use the Firefox cookie extractor in Python, is to open your web inspector and check what session headers are sent.

For example, in [Chrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome):

```
Remote Address:111.11.111.111:80
Request URL:http://example.com
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:fr,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,es;q=0.4,de;q=0.2
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:_ga=GA1.2.228078207.1409667791; mp_d6ebe82547b18c335122656ad5df6c0e_mixpanel=%7B%22distinct_id%22%3A%20%221492964fd1e75-0b7e66217-39740157-15f900-1492964fd1f1b8%22%2C%22%24initial_referrer%22%3A%20%22%24direct%22%2C%22%24initial_referring_domain%22%3A%20%22%24direct%22%7D; rack.session=BAh7B0kiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOgZFVEkiRTMyZGMwMTc0OWMwNmE2YzBjYWQ4%0AMjM1ODdjNGZlNzY4NDdmZjNkY2ZhYWIzNWNiYmYxZWM1MjkwMGM0YTNhYzQG%0AOwBGSSIcd2FyZGVuLnVzZXIuZGVmYXVsdC5rZXkGOwBUVToZV2FyZGVuOjpH%0AaXRIdWI6OlVzZXJ7BzoMYXR0cmlic3sNSSIKbG9naW4GOwBGSSISYXVnLXJp%0AZWRpbmdlcgY7AFRJIgdpZAY7AEZpA%2BwPHkkiD2F2YXRhcl91cmwGOwBGSSI4%0AaHR0cHM6Ly9hdmF0YXJzLmdpdGh1YnVzZXJjb250ZW50LmNvbS91LzE5NzAx%0ANTY%2Fdj0zBjsAVEkiEGdyYXZhdGFyX2lkBjsARkkiAAY7AFRJIg9zaXRlX2Fk%0AbWluBjsARkZJIgluYW1lBjsARkkiF0F1Z3VzdGluIFJpZWRpbmdlcgY7AFRJ%0AIgxjb21wYW55BjsARkkiC0NvcGFzcwY7AFRJIgplbWFpbAY7AEZJIgAGOwBU%0AOgp0b2tlbkkiLTExMzg4NDkzNGIzZDkxNTMzOGJlOTU3YjcxZTA3OTU3ZDhh%0AYWQ2YjEGOwBU%0A--cf66a01faadf81e2cf2997a9e01c7dccdc5c67ba
Host:example.com
Pragma:no-cache
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36
```

Here the following command will work:

```
wget --header "Cookie: rack.session=BAh7B0kiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOgZFVEkiRTMyZGMwMTc0OWMwNmE2YzBjYWQ4%0AMjM1ODdjNGZlNzY4NDdmZjNkY2ZhYWIzNWNiYmYxZWM1MjkwMGM0YTNhYzQG%0AOwBGSSIcd2FyZGVuLnVzZXIuZGVmYXVsdC5rZXkGOwBUVToZV2FyZGVuOjpH%0AaXRIdWI6OlVzZXJ7BzoMYXR0cmlic3sNSSIKbG9naW4GOwBGSSISYXVnLXJp%0AZWRpbmdlcgY7AFRJIgdpZAY7AEZpA%2BwPHkkiD2F2YXRhcl91cmwGOwBGSSI4%0AaHR0cHM6Ly9hdmF0YXJzLmdpdGh1YnVzZXJjb250ZW50LmNvbS91LzE5NzAx%0ANTY%2Fdj0zBjsAVEkiEGdyYXZhdGFyX2lkBjsARkkiAAY7AFRJIg9zaXRlX2Fk%0AbWluBjsARkZJIgluYW1lBjsARkkiF0F1Z3VzdGluIFJpZWRpbmdlcgY7AFRJ%0AIgxjb21wYW55BjsARkkiC0NvcGFzcwY7AFRJIgplbWFpbAY7AEZJIgAGOwBU%0AOgp0b2tlbkkiLTExMzg4NDkzNGIzZDkxNTMzOGJlOTU3YjcxZTA3OTU3ZDhh%0AYWQ2YjEGOwBU%0A--cf66a01faadf81e2cf2997a9e01c7dccdc5c67ba"  http://example.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Does the page have a "Remember me" option. If so, you can export the cookie file (see this: http://blog.mithis.net/archives/python/90-firefox3-cookies-in-python) and use --load-cookies in wget.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want some kind of web automation tool rather a straight downloader like wget.

The one that comes to my mind is **[WatiN](http://watin.sourceforge.net/)** but there are many others like this.

---

**Edit**: Actually, **[Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/)** is probably a better fit.  If you're not a programmer, it has a simple point and click "macro" type mode in Firefox.

Comment: Those don’t look like what I am looking for. I need a way of running a program from a script or something so that it can be scheduled to run automatically in the background now and then.